# Is Google playstore App review increasing my firebase reads?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-play

I have a flutter application that I need to publish on playstore. It uses firebase firestore as it's Database, and also uses snapshotListners. The number of reads during the developing phase (Three developers) was around 2k-3k. But when I submitted the App for review along with the demo login credentials, the number of reads increased to 51k in the following 3 hours. Is my suspicion right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the review process of your app it may be run in automated (and possibly also manual) tests. So if your app reads from Firestore when it is used, it is indeed expected that this will happen during the review too.

Answer (score 1):

I’m suspecting the same thing. I submitted an update to my app on Google Play Console at approximately 11:35pm local time and I instantly saw a spike in reads in my Firestore Instance. What doesn’t make any sense to me is that there weren’t any writes nor deletes so how was the reviewer causing so many reads without having anything to read from? I also checked on the Firebase Analytics Dashboard and there was a single user on an unknown location using v1.0.2 of my app which is the version that I had just submitted to Google for review. Anywho, when the reads normalized again I proceeded to go to the Google Play Console and my update was approved to be published.

In essence, I think the short answer to your question is a yes.